# localstack docker gives error Permission denied: '/tmp/localstack/server.test.pem.key'

Tags: docker, mocking, ubuntu-18.04, docker-machine, localstack

On my ubuntu 18 machine I cannot run latest docker image of localstack.
Even if the end message displayed as "Ready" I still can not access it using the following command.

```
awslocal --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4575 sns list-topics

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:4575/"
```

docker run localstack/localstack  also shows an error :
***[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/localstack/server.test.pem.key'***

```
docker run localstack/localstack  

Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
2020-04-09 04:28:19,502 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
2020-04-09 04:28:19,504 INFO supervisord started with pid 13
2020-04-09 04:28:20,509 INFO spawned: 'dashboard' with pid 19
2020-04-09 04:28:20,511 INFO spawned: 'infra' with pid 20
(. .venv/bin/activate; bin/localstack web)
2020-04-09 04:28:20,515 INFO success: dashboard entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
(. .venv/bin/activate; exec bin/localstack start --host)
Starting local dev environment. CTRL-C to quit.
2020-04-09 04:28:21,877 INFO success: infra entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-04-09T04:28:25:INFO:localstack.utils.common: Unable to store key/cert files for custom SSL certificate: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/localstack/server.test.pem.key'
!WARNING! - Looks like you have configured $LAMBDA_REMOTE_DOCKER=1 - please make sure to configure $HOST_TMP_FOLDER to point to your host's $TMPDIR
Starting edge router (http port 4566)...
Starting edge router (https port 443)...
Starting mock API Gateway (http port 4567)...
2020-04-09T04:28:25:INFO:localstack.multiserver: Starting multi API server process on port 51492
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
Starting mock CloudFormation (http port 4581)...
Starting mock CloudWatch (http port 4582)...
Starting mock DynamoDB (http port 4569)...
Starting mock DynamoDB Streams service (http port 4570)...
Starting mock EC2 (http port 4597)...
Starting mock ES service (http port 4578)...
Starting mock Firehose service (http port 4573)...
Starting mock IAM (http port 4593)...
Starting mock Kinesis (http port 4568)...
Starting mock KMS (http port 4599)...
Starting mock Lambda service (http port 4574)...
Starting mock CloudWatch Logs (http port 4586)...
Starting mock Redshift (http port 4577)...
Starting mock Route53 (http port 4580)...
Starting mock S3 (http port 4572)...
Starting mock Secrets Manager (http port 4584)...
Starting mock SES (http port 4579)...
Starting mock SNS (http port 4575)...
Starting mock SQS (http port 4576)...
Starting mock SSM (http port 4583)...
Starting mock STS (http port 4592)...
Starting mock Cloudwatch Events (http port 4587)...
Starting mock StepFunctions (http port 4585)...
Ready.
```

Comment: If you're using `awslocal` you don't need to specify the `--endpoint-url`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should grant localstack process with permissions to write in the `tmp` folder.

Add these lines to the localstack's `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
   tmpfs:
  - /tmp/localstack:exec,mode=600
```

As in this example:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    container_name: localstack
    ports:
      - "4574:4574"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=lambda
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp/localstack:exec,mode=600
```

Where `mode=600` is the octal mode of [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) that allows read & write.